# JPA: datatype of output of a select query

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Consider the below code.

```
@Repository
public interface PurchaseOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderID> {


    @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM PURCHASE_ORDER where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    PurchaseOrder getPO(Long id);
}
```

I have an object called `PurchaseOrder` and i used the jpa interface to create a repository from it.

about the method `getPO` what can i expect from the output of the query?
Does jpa automatically put the output to a `PurchaseOrder` 
 object?

Comment: Yes, because you told it so in `extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from @ochi's comments Yes, because you told it so in extends

```
JpaRepository < **PurchaseOrder**, PurchaseOrderID >
```

if you have a look at the JpaRepository class you will find logic of how the entity class is passed and used via generics.